# Динамическое обновление значений в ChartBar используя PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qtimer, qchartview

Недавно начал использовать *GUI* библиотеку *PyQt5* и столкнулся с проблемой динамического обновления значений в графике (`ChartBar`).

Хочу чтобы для начала значения графика (пусть будут рандомные) обновлялись к примеру каждую секунду. 
Почитал материалы по данной тематики и могу предположить, что решение проблемы будет использование метода `connect()`, в теле которого будет функция перезаписи значений графика. Этот же метод будет активироваться от счётчика таймера раз в секунду.

Дополнительно пишу мою реализацию на данный момент:

```
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
import sys, random
import time

class MainWidow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800 ,600)

        set0 = QBarSet("Min")
        set1 = QBarSet("Mid")
        set2 = QBarSet("Max")

        r1 = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(50)]
        set0.append(r1)
        set1.append([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(50)])
        set2.append([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(50)])

        series = QStackedBarSeries()
        series.append(set0)
        series.append(set1)
        series.append(set2)
        series.setBarWidth(0.9)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitle("Simple percentbarchart example")
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        categories = [str(i+1) for i in range(50)]
        axisX = QBarCategoryAxis()
        axisX.append(categories)
        chart.addAxis(axisX,Qt.AlignBottom)
        series.attachAxis(axisX)

        axisY = QValueAxis()
        chart.addAxis(axisY,Qt.AlignLeft)
        series.attachAxis(axisY)

        chart.legend().setVisible(True)
        chart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        chartView = QChartView(chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setCentralWidget(chartView)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window  = MainWidow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Хочу что бы для начала значения графика (пусть будут рандомные) обновлялись к примеру каждую секунду. Почитал материалы по данной тематики и могу предположить что решение проблемы будет использование метода . connect () в теле когорого будет функция перезаписи значений графика. Этот же метод будет активироваться от счётчика таймера раз в секунду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QRandomGenerator
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChartView, QLineSeries, QChart, QSplineSeries, QValueAxis
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class DynamicSpline(QChart):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.m_step = 0
        self.m_x = 5
        self.m_y = 1
        # Инициализировать изображение
        self.series = QSplineSeries(self)
        green_pen = QPen(Qt.red)
        green_pen.setWidth(3)
        self.series.setPen(green_pen)
        self.axisX = QValueAxis()
        self.axisY = QValueAxis()
        self.series.append(self.m_x, self.m_y)

        self.addSeries(self.series)
        self.addAxis(self.axisX, Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.addAxis(self.axisY, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.series.attachAxis(self.axisX)
        self.series.attachAxis(self.axisY)
        self.axisX.setTickCount(5)
        self.axisX.setRange(0, 10)
        self.axisY.setRange(-5, 10)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.handleTimeout)
        self.timer.start()

    def handleTimeout(self):
        x = self.plotArea().width() / self.axisX.tickCount()
        y = (self.axisX.max() - self.axisX.min()) / self.axisX.tickCount()
        self.m_x += y

        # В PyQt 5.11.3 и выше, QRandomGenerator.global() был переименован в global_()

        self.m_y = QRandomGenerator.global_().bounded(5) - 2.5
        self.series.append(self.m_x, self.m_y)
        self.scroll(x, 0)
        if self.m_x >= 100:
            self.timer.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    chart = DynamicSpline()
    chart.setTitle("Dynamic spline chart")
    chart.legend().hide()
    chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.AllAnimations)

    view = QChartView(chart)
    view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing) 
    view.resize(400, 300)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То что надо! Адаптирую данное решение для своей задачи